# How to show category of entry within relationship field

Tags: categories, relationships

How do I show the category of an entry within the native EE relationship field?

I've tried using this which doesn't seem to work. (EE v3.4.3)

```
{relationship_field:categories}
    {relationship_field:category_name}
{/relationship_field:categories}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should try something like this:

```
{relationship_field}
    {relationship_field:categories}
        {category_name}
    {/relationship_field:categories}
{/relationship_field}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked.